# Weird make behavior with rule

Tags: makefile, gnu

I have a rule that create a file and an other one that copy it. But on running make, the prerequisites of the rule is called twice but I don't know why!

If I have a $(shell ./myscript) in prerequisite instead of the actual $(warning ...), the script is called twice!

**The Makefile that reproduces the bug:**

```
NAME := test

$(NAME):
    @touch $@

install-$(NAME): $(NAME) install-copy-$(NAME)

.PHONY: install-$(NAME)
.PRECIOUS: %.copy

.SECONDEXPANSION:

%.copy: $$*
    @cp $< $@

install-copy-%: $$(warning START) $$*.copy $$(warning END)
    @echo done
```

**Actual output:**

```
make: START
make: START
make: END
done
```

**Expected output:**

```
make: START
make: END
done
```

Why START is outputed twice?
If I have a function that call a script instead of the $(warning) the script is called twice.

I have no idea...
I want to keep the .SECONDEXPANSION because I don't want that the $(shell script ...) or the $(warning ...) was called when the rule is not called.
I can't list all the files that will be installed in the .PRECIOUS, because I don't know since this file are generated by an external script. (like doxygen). With the .PRECIOUS: %.copy the first time START is outputed twice, but once the file exist, START is outputed once...

Thanks!

**The Makefile with real case:**

```
NAME := test
INSTALL_DIR := saved

# generate the documentation into $$*/
generateDoc-%:
    touch $*/$(shell head /dev/urandom | tr -dc A-Za-z0-9 | head -c 13 ; echo '')

install-$(NAME): generateDoc-$(NAME) install-doc-$(NAME)

.PHONY: install-$(NAME)
.PRECIOUS: $(INSTALL_DIR)/%

.SECONDEXPANSION:

$(INSTALL_DIR)/%: $$(NAME)/$$*
    cp $< $@

install-doc-%: $$(warning START) $$(subst $$*,$$(INSTALL_DIR),$$(shell find $$* -type f)) $$(warning END)
    @echo done
```

Comment: I don't know, but putting `warning` statements in a prerequisite list is seriously weird.

Comment: yes, its just to show that the prerequisite are read twice...
Instead of this warning I have a shell command to list the file that I need to install.
This command is costly, and I don't want to launch it twice.

Comment: if doxygen creates files in **/usr/doc**, then `shell ls $$*/documentation` will find no files to copy from there

Comment: No, first we generate documentation with generateDoc-%:
It generate documentation file into test/documentation
Then we call install-doc-% that install the documentation into /usr/doc:
ls test/documentation will found all the generated files.

Comment: But the target `
$(NAME)/documentation/%` is up-to-date, `cp test/documentation/%` to  `/usr/doc` will not happen.

Comment: you need to have doxygen on your computer to generate the documentation and you need some files with doxygen documentation. That's why I give you the first Makefile, because for the real case you need more stuff.

Comment: I've updated my question, with a new Makefile that reproduce the real case behavior, without needing doxygen. You have just to run make install-test and you will show! Thanks and sorry for the convenience.

Answer (score 1):

`make -d` explains that after making target `test`, it tries to make target `install-copy-test` (that invokes the first pair of START/END). After that it looks for a rule with intermediate file `test.copy`.

All this on assumption that you run `make install-test`

```
> make install-test -n
touch test
make: START
make: END
make: START
make: END
cp test test.copy
done
rm test.copy
```

The natural fix would be to specify

```
.PRECIOUS: $(NAME).copy
```

Comment: I can't add the .copy in PRECIOUS, I can just add PRECIOUS: %.copy but don't works. (works only when file already exist, but not the first time).
I can't add all the .copy name, because its file generated by an external script (doxygen). So I run the doxygen command, then run a $(shell find in the doxygen directory, to get all files to install)., So the solution don't works :(

Comment: You can put `.PRECIOUS: $(NAME).copy` even before `.SECONDEXPANSION:` (actually, also `$(NAME):` can be moved above).

Comment: I meant, `$(NAME).copy`, not `%.copy` !

Comment: Yes, but I can't. Here its just an example to reproduce my case. In my real case, its not $(NAME).copy but all file generated by doxygen. I can't add in .PRECIOUS all the filename that doxygen will generate. You understand?

Comment: Let's try to prepare a simple example that does represent your use case better. Also, do you need to keep the *.copy* files at all? Maybe, it's good that **make** removes them in the end?

Comment: I've updated my question. The file must be kept since this make is used for install documentation.